# Simple group of order 504

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

As we know,there are 9 Sylow 2-subgroup in the Simple group of order 504.Can anyone prove it only by Sylow's theorem?

(you can't use knowledge about PSL(2,8))

Comment: Questions like this are much better suited to math.stackexchange.com. Math overflow is for research level questions

Answer (score 1):

This assertion had proved on the page 311 in:

F. N. Cole, Simple Groups as Far as Order 660. American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 15, No. 4 (1893), pp. 303-315.

Comment: I have read his article,but the terminologies he used are so hard to understand,I want to find a easy proof with Sylow's theorem